# DIV's behaving differently in IE vs Firefox

Tags: css, html

If you run the simple HTML page found at:

http://ss.bigwavesoftware.net/2.htm

in IE8 and FireFox 3.5.8, the DIV's display differently.  In IE they behave as block elements and FireFox they behave as inline elements.  I need them to behave as inline in both browsers.  Can someone suggest a workaround to make them display inline in IE8 as well as FireFox?

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="display: inline; float: none; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid red;">Left Box
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline; float: right; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid green;">Right Box
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Type the code in, as you would normal text, and then you can either: select the code and click on the 101010 button (above the textarea that you typed into), or you can indent each line of code by four spaces (these are for code blocks), for inline code just prepend, and append, a back-tick.

Comment: Thanks, @mercator, I was just about to do that... =)

Comment: @ricebowl thanks for your explanation. I was just about to do *that*. ;)

Comment: @mercator, ah... *synchronicity* ... =)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I will remember for next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the order of your divs and it will work. That is put the first one second and the second one first in the markup.

```
<html>
<body>
     <div style="display: inline; float: right; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid green;">Right Box
    </div>
     <div style="display: inline; float: none; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid red;">Left Box
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This suggestion along with the DOCTYPE suggestion (from above) fixed the issue.  Thanks everyone!  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Add a doctype at the very start of your document. It's being rendered in [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html). E.g.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
... etc.
```

Oh, and what exactly do you mean by "behave as inline"? Do you simply mean you want them to appear side-by-side, or do you actually *want* the width and height to be ignored (as [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365705/divs-behaving-differently-in-ie-vs-firefox/2365778#2365778) pointed out)? Because you won't be able to do the latter for floated elements. The `display: inline` is useless on floats ([except to fix IE6 bugs](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html)), because ["inline" floats automatically turn into block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo).

Comment: Good point, but irrelevant here. Having the right-floated div first works even in the skeleton html provided.

Comment: @Robusto Not irrelevant, because quirks mode causes IE8 to display both divs as blocks, which only the right one should be (according to the specs). Adding the doctype both fixes that and allows both divs to appear on the same line (answering the original question). Just adding a doctype still leaves at least IE7 broken, though. Swapping the divs fixes that.

Comment: Yes, I had removed my DOCTYPE b/c it didn't have an effect on my original example.  However, by the time I had isolated the issue with a much simpler HTML from the original page, the DOCTYPE did make a difference.  Adding my XHTML STRICT DOCTYPE back in along with the comment to move the float:none element to the end (my example has two DIV's but the original has three), fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set height and width on inline elements. If you want the boxes to be laid out as they are in Firefox, remove the display: inline and float the left-hand box.

Comment: Removing `display:inline` isn't really necessary, as `float:left` should cause them to be displayed as block elements anyway (overruling `display:inline`).

Comment: In fact there are occasionally times where I put `display:inline` on a floating element just because this fixes some IE7 CSS bug . . . even though in a W3C compliant browser having `display:inline` on a float should do nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

use float: left instead of float: none in the first div (the one on the left).

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="display: inline; float: left; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid red;">Left Box
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline; float: right; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid green;">Right Box
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```